# Trying to understand logic example from book

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I would like help understanding the following "example":

> $(Ex)(Ey)\overline{x=y} \space \& \space (Ex)(Ey)(Ez)(Eu)(v)(v=x \lor v=y \lor v=z \space \lor v=u) \space \&$
>   $\& (Ex)(Ey)((z)(z=x \lor z=y) \lor (Ez)(Eu)(\overline{x=y} \space\&\space \overline{x=z} \space\&\space \overline{x=u} \space\&\space \overline{y=z} \space\&\space$
>     $\&\space \overline{y=u} \space\&\space \overline{z=u}))$

Please note that I have quoted the example *exactly* as shown in the book, including line breaks with extra &s, and where $E = \exists$.

The author immediately states that the formula is only valid in domains of size 2 and 4, and invalid everywhere else. No proof is given.

My thoughts (assuming every member of the domain is unique):

- $(Ex)(Ey)\overline{x=y}$ is always false when n=1, otherwise always true.
- $(Ex)(Ey)(Ez)(Eu)(v)(v=x \lor v=y \lor v=z \space \& \lor v=u)$

  - $(Ex)(v)(v=x)$

    - Is it correct to say that $x$ is not fixed, but rather as $v$ iterates over the domain, a new $x$ is selected for each $v_i$ that happens to be $v_i$ itself? In which case $(Ex)(v)(v=x)$ is a tautology, as well as the entire wff (i.e. the wff expressed by the 2nd bullet)?
    - because $Ex$ proceeds $(v)$, is it more correct to say that there is at least one $x$ such that every $v$ is equal to it? In which case the sentence is *only* valid in a domain of size 1, as well as the entire sentence? (if the quantifiers are reversed, is my statement above correct?)
- $(Ex)(Ey)(z)(z=x \lor z=y)$ ... see bullet above.
- $(Ex)(Ey)(Ez)(Eu)(\overline{x=y} \space\&\space \overline{x=z} \space\&\space \overline{x=u} \space\&\space \overline{y=z} \space\&\space\overline{y=u} \space\&\space \overline{z=u})$ can become $''(Ex)(Ey)(\overline{x=y}) \space\& \space (Ex)(Ez)(\overline{x=z})...''$ which turn can become $''(Ex)(Ey)(\overline{x=y}) \space\& \space (Ep)(Ez)(\overline{p=z})...''$ such that each term has unique variables. This means that the entire sentence is only valid in domains of size > 1? (same as first bullet)

So, I'm unable to reproduce what the author suggests. Also, it seems to me that the conjunctions and disjunctions in the individual sentences i've selected don't seem to make a difference (say if a conjunction was replaced by a disjunction or vice versa).

Comment: $(Ex)(v)(v=x)$ says that there is one at least $x$ that remains fixed as $v$ ranges over the domain.  (And every $v$ is equal to $x$)  This is NOT a clause of the sentence quoted in the question.

Comment: Changing conjuctions to disjunctions and vice versa would completely change the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: @JimH By meaning, do you mean in the "ordinary language" sense, or in the semantic T/F sense? I understand the former...would $(Ex)(Ey)(Ez)(Eu)(v)(v=x \space\&\space v=y \space\&\space v=z \space \space\&\space v=u)$ mean there is at most one, and the extra equality terms beyond the first are redundant?

Comment: The first conjunct means: "at least two". This is because the formula claims that we have (at least) and $x$ and an $y$ that must be different.

Comment: The second conjunct means: "not more than four". This is because the formula claims that there are (at least) $x, y, z, u$ and every other element $v$ **must be** equal to one of the previous four.

Comment: But, the second formula does not precludes that there are only two or three, because the variables exisentially quantified can be instantiated to the same object.

Comment: So, up to now, "at least two and not more than four" can be: $2,3,4$. We have to exclude the case of three.

Comment: Thus, tthe issue is: is the third conjunct apt to exclude the three objects case ? We have to check with a "model" with three distinct elements: $a,b,c$.

Comment: The part $(Ex)(Ey)(z)(z=x ∨ z=y)$ is clearly not satisfied in it; if $a,b,c$ are distinct, there is no way to interpret $x$ and $y$ such that for any $z$: either $z=x$ or $z=y$. If $x=a$ and $y=b$, then the case $z=c$ will falsify the formula (because $c \ne a$ and $c \ne b$).

Comment: And also $x=y=a$ will not do. And the same for the other possible combinations.

Comment: The other part of the third conjunct is: $(Ex)(Ey)(Ez)(Eu)(x \ne y \& x \ne z \& x \ne u \& y \ne z \& y \ne u \& z \ne u)$ says that there "at least four". Note that the previous one says "at most four".

Comment: Thus, "cooking them" together: "at least two (i.e. $\ge 2$) and at most four (and thus, up to now: $2 \le n \le 4$) and either exactly two or at most four".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(Ex)(Ey)\overline{x=y}$ tells us that there are at least two distinct objects in the domain.

$(Ex)(Ey)(Ez)(Eu)(v)(v=x \lor v=y \lor v=z \space \lor v=u)$ tells us that there are at most 4 elements in the domain.  There are four or fewer things, named $x$, $y$, $z$, and $u$ and for any $v$, $v$ is one of those things.

$(Ex)(Ey)((z)(z=x \lor z=y) \lor (Ez)(Eu)(\overline{x=y} \space\&\space \overline{x=z} \space\&\space \overline{x=u} \space\&\space \overline{y=z} \space\&\space \overline{y=u} \space\&\space \overline{z=u}))$

The first clause $(Ex)(Ey)((z)(z=x \lor z=y)$ is true when the domain contains  at most two elements.
The second $(Ex)(Ey)(Ez)(Eu)(\overline{x=y} \space\&\space \overline{x=z} \space\&\space \overline{x=u} \space\&\space \overline{y=z} \space\&\space \overline{y=u}\space\&\space \overline{z=u})$  is true when there are at least four elements in the domain.
Note that the sentence asserts that clause 1 or clause 2 is true.

Comment: I grasp the intent of the second sentence, but... if there _were_ four, then how could any individual term be true? (Ex)(v)(v=x)(Ex)(v)(v=x) couldn't be true because not every $v$ is equal to $x$, and the same for the other three.

Comment: @Lugh You cannot distribute the universal quantifier across disjunction.

Comment: .@JimH Thank-you for reminding me. The text I'm using now doesn't make that rule explicit, and it would appear that I forgot.