# How would we symbolize the following sentence logically?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

There are at least four distinct people. [ P(x) : x is a person ]

I am a little confused on how to symbolize "at least". Do I use the "and" sign and denote P(X) four times?

Comment: $\exists a\exists b\exists c\exists d\colon P(a)\land P(b)\land P(c)\land P(d)\land a\ne b\land a\ne c\land a\ne d\land b\ne c\land b\ne d\land c\ne d$

Answer (score 0):

The answer was provided in Hagen's comment on your question (not sure why it was a comment instead of an answer, so you could close the question).

This answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2433700/400384, to a similar question I asked (only 2 *or* 4) explains nicely how each part of the sentence achieves the outcome. The comments on the question explain a bit further.